# Can i run scripts created in Visual Studio 2010 Premium version in Visual Studio 2010 ultimate version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have created Coded UI scripts in VS2010 Premium version. Now i want to install VS 2010 Ultimate version for Performance Testing. 
Will my scripts those were created in 2010 Premium version run in 2010 ultimate version without any further changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Vivek. It will definitely run without any changes. Post over here if you are facing any issue while doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any issue within different editions of VS but you may need to copy some DLLs if you are trying with different versions like 2012 VS scripts in 2013 VS. you may use relevant Test Agents if you are running outside VS.